# Json.net with multiple datasets

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I'm using Json.net's `JsonTextWriter` to create JSON data object from a web service.  I have:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
Dim sw As New StringWriter(sb)
Dim writer As JsonWriter = New JsonTextWriter(sw)

If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then

    writer.WriteStartObject()
    writer.WritePropertyName("authors")
    writer.WriteStartArray()
    For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        writer.WriteStartObject()
        writer.WritePropertyName("key")
        writer.WriteValue(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("CoAuthorID"))
        writer.WritePropertyName("text")
        writer.WriteValue(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("CoAuthorName").ToString)
        writer.WritePropertyName("program")
        writer.WriteValue(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("program").ToString)
        writer.WritePropertyName("number")
        writer.WriteValue(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("n").ToString)
        writer.WriteEndObject()
    Next
    writer.WriteEndArray()
    writer.WriteEndObject()
End If
```

But now I want to add a second table such as

```
writer.WriteStartObject()
writer.WritePropertyName("pubs")
writer.WriteStartArray()
For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(1).Rows.Count - 1
    writer.WriteStartObject()
    writer.WritePropertyName("pmid")
    writer.WriteValue(ds.Tables(1).Rows(i).Item("pmid"))
    writer.WritePropertyName("text")
    writer.WriteValue(ds.Tables(1).Rows(i).Item("Reference").ToString)
    writer.WriteEndObject()
Next
writer.WriteEndArray()
writer.WriteEndObject()
```

I want to be able to work with the data on the client side such as `JSONData.authors` and `JSONData.pubs`.  When I work with one data table everything is fine but if I combine the teo then I can't read the data.  It seems that it is missing a comma between the two JSON objects. If I add it manually, it chokes.  I am going to "assume" that I am missing a line of code between the two datatables but I'm not sure what that is.  Any help is appreciated.  I think it might have something to do with `WriteStartConstructor` but I don't really know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `pubs` array should be a property on the root object, not a new object.  If you were to just add the code as-is, you'd essentially be writing JSON that would look like this:

```
{"authors":[...]}{"pubs":[...}}
```

As you can probably notice, you just have two distinct objects with an `authors` and `pubs` property respectively.  Like that, it's not a valid JSON string.

You probably want to build up your JSON like this:

```
writer.WriteStartObject()
If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
    writer.WritePropertyName("authors")
    writer.WriteStartArray()
    For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        writer.WriteStartObject()
        writer.WritePropertyName("key")
        writer.WriteValue(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("CoAuthorID"))
        writer.WritePropertyName("text")
        writer.WriteValue(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("CoAuthorName").ToString)
        writer.WritePropertyName("program")
        writer.WriteValue(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("program").ToString)
        writer.WritePropertyName("number")
        writer.WriteValue(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("n").ToString)
        writer.WriteEndObject()
    Next
    writer.WriteEndArray()
End If
If ds.Tables(1).Rows.Count > 0 Then
    writer.WritePropertyName("pubs")
    writer.WriteStartArray()
    For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(1).Rows.Count - 1
        writer.WriteStartObject()
        writer.WritePropertyName("pmid")
        writer.WriteValue(ds.Tables(1).Rows(i).Item("pmid"))
        writer.WritePropertyName("text")
        writer.WriteValue(ds.Tables(1).Rows(i).Item("Reference").ToString)
        writer.WriteEndObject()
    Next
    writer.WriteEndArray()
End If
writer.WriteEndObject()
```